# phpmyAdmin displays command instead of value?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyAdmin version 4.0.10.20. Upon login to phpmyAdmin, while browsing mysql tables, it displays, php command E.g. Following is displayed in Username column **server_privileges.php?username=user1&token=be3ef6a2b97ac014544f563** instead of just 'user1'. 
If you DoubleClick or Edit that cell, correct value 'user1' is displayed. I am using Mysql version is 5.1.55, PHP version is 5.3.6. How do I fix display to stop showing php command? Is there a bug in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: have you tried updating your phpmyadmin? that problem might occur due to some bugs of old versions.

Comment: With your older PHP you cannot upgrade phpMyAdmin; note that PHP 5.3's end of life was on 14 Aug 2014.

Comment: We are using old version PHP (5.3) and Mysql  (5.1.55). Newer version of phpmyAdmin does not support that.) so it has to be 4.0.10.20 or older.

Comment: Well, support for phpMyAdmin 4.0.x stopped on 2017-04-01.